# Load css depending depending on protocol of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-face

I have 2 @font-face in the same css file

```
@font-face {
    /* code for https://site.con */
    }
@font-face {
        /* code for http://site.con */
    }
```

and i need load only the first @font-face when the site is https, and the only the second when the site is http.

Is it possible? with js/jquery or another method?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two rules?

Comment: If you're doing this because of a mixed content error, you can just use the https for both.

Comment: @MarcBarbeau yes,i have a mixed content error, but im working with the both sites, https and http

Comment: If the only difference between the rules is `http` and `https`, then your css rules can just drop that off.  `//yourUrl/path/file.ext` will use whatever protocol the page is currently using

Comment: Can't you use `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Foo` without defining https or http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with javascript/jquery, solution steps:

1. check if the site is https or not.

```
if (location.protocol != 'https:')
{
//http font
} else {
//https font
}
```

2. load the correct font.

```
$("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" + 
                                "@font-face {\n" +
                                    "\tfont-family: \"myFont\";\n" + 
                                    "\tsrc: local('☺'), url('myFont.otf') format('opentype');\n" + 
                                "}\n" + 
                                    "\tp.myClass {\n" + 
                                    "\tfont-family: myFont !important;\n" + 
                                "}\n" + 
                            "</style>");
```